# Manipulate text-shadow with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to manipulate text-shadow specific.

I've tried this,

```
this.css("text-shadow", '#FFD800 1px 1px 0');
```

and its working. But i want to make more.

I'm trying to:

```
sh="";
for (i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
    sh += ',#FFD800 '+i+'px '+i+'px 0';
}           

this.css("text-shadow", sh);
```

This is not work. How can i make to work?
Thanks.

Comment: you are trying to put multiple values in `sh`. What exactly you want to do? Are you trying to set some random value for text-shadow?

Comment: i want to make simulate 3D view in short way. Because i must make not use any plugin.

Comment: have you tried putting hardcode value of text-shadow instead of generating it using loop. Please try that and let me know what exact value you want to use. Post a jsfiddle link so that we can help you in better way.

Answer (score 0):

**[`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** can only apply to `jQuery` object so change

```
this.css("text-shadow", sh);
```

to

```
$(this).css("text-shadow", sh);
```

Also there is an extra `,` at the starting of the style value, to avoid that use something like following

```js
var sh = [];
for (i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
  sh.push('#FFD800 ' + i + 'px ' + i + 'px 0');
}

$(this).css("text-shadow", sh.join(','));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

DEMO

```js
var sh = [];
for (i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
  sh.push('#FFD800 ' + i + 'px ' + i + 'px 0');
}

$('div').css("text-shadow", sh.join(','));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="font-size:30px">DEMO</div>
```

Comment: @user2729439 : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
 this.css("text-shadow", sh);
```

to

```
 $(this).css("text-shadow", sh);
```

.css is a jQuery function and it works on a proper selector

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/wwqxdjvp/